# Sum two vector and store stl algorithm

Tags: c++, stl

I have two vectors and I want to do something like

```
v2[i] = v1[i] +v2[i];
```

I have tried `std::copy`, but obviously that only do `v2[i] = v1[i];`

Is there any algorithm in the STL that performs this sum?

Comment: Note: you could use std::valarray: `v2 += v1;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`std:::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

```
std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.begin(), std::plus<>());
```

Comment: C++ is beautiful